# How can I change the model on a Backbone js view "safely"?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am experimenting with master-detail stuff using Backbone js and Marionette. How can I go about changing the model for a view? I want the view's model listeners to be removed from the old model and applied to the new one. Ditto for other similar stuff related to the model. Anyone got some 'changeModel' code to do this cleanly?

Comment: Any code example to show us ?

Comment: Closed? WTF? Not a real question? How so?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to just destroy the old view and make a new one based on a different model?  In this example I pass the model itself into the ItemViewOptions, and on the model I have some defining characteristics... and since the model comes from the server I can manipulate what happens View.  This one is for binding a dynamic templates, but I guess you could do something with events as well. This would require you to destroy whatever you have first rather than re-binding everything.

```
node = Backbone.Model.extend

nodes = Backbone.Collection.extend
    model: node
    url: ->
        Myapp.rooturl + "/api/node"
    initialize: (nodes) ->
        @fetch()    

nodeView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend
    initialize: (options) -> 
        @template = "#" + options.model.attributes.nodetemplate + "-template"
    tagName: 'div'

nodesView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend
    itemView: nodeView
    itemViewOptions: @model
```

Comment: I have already got it working making a new view. I was just wondering how to make the "keep the view" version work. I supposed its not too much of a big deal to make a new view since most likely everything would need to be re-rendered anyway.